# Percentage calculation with different total marks

Tags: mathematical-statistics, percentage

I am having confusion for percentage calculation for marks I have obtained in my exam.

I have 9 subjects with total 900 marks (100 marks each) and out of them I got 699.

Two more subjects with total 100 marks (50 marks each) and out of them I got 48 and 46 marks.

Now, how can I calculate the percentage I obtained for total 11 subjects?

Answer (score 0):

Your total mark looks like $(699 + 48 + 46) / (900 + 100) = 793/1000 = 79.3\%$ to me.

It looks good that you got $96\%$ and $92\%$ on your two courses with weight $50$.

But your institution gives those less weight, so I strongly guess that the overall percent is going to be reported as above. That is certainly what would apply at my own University.